# let if/else break out of one loop in a list comprehension that loops over two ranges

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I Have a list comprehension with an if else statement that loops over two ranges.

Is it possible, using list comprehensions, to break out one of the two loops when the if condition test false?

In my code example I want an ordered list with all unique combinations (with a specified maximum length) of the letter given, in the order of 'my' alphabet.

```py
str_len = 3
my_list = ["A", "H"]
alphabet = [" ", "A", "H"]
for i in range(str_len-1):
    my_list = [i+j if i[-1] != " " else i for i in my_list for j in alphabet]
print(my_list)
```

This is what I get.

> ['A ', 'A ', 'A ', 'AA ', 'AAA', 'AAH', 'AH ', 'AHA', 'AHH', 'H ', 'H ', 'H ', 'HA ', 'HAA', 'HAH', 'HH ', 'HHA', 'HHH']

However I want no duplicates. like this:

> ['A ', 'AA ', 'AAA', 'AAH', 'AH ', 'AHA', 'AHH', 'H ', 'HA ', 'HAA', 'HAH', 'HH ', 'HHA', 'HHH']

Edit: specified I want an ordered list.

Comment: If you don't want to use external libraries as in the answers you would get, you would have to use normal nested loop, and check for every new item if it is already in the newly created list. In list comprehension it is not possible.

Comment: Ah, to bad. The problem is of course solvable with nested for loops but I liked the idea of a list comprehension.

Comment: You're modifying variables while looping over them ( `my_list`) and shadowing variables in the loop (`i`) - rather a no-go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> ```
> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
> ```
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

With the `itertools.combinations` you only can define a static length of combinations, but then you can combine it with [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
str_min_len = 1
str_max_len = 3
my_list = ["A", "H"]
result = chain.from_iterable(
   combinations(my_list, i) for i in range(str_min_len, str_max_len))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thnx, your comment pointed me in the right direction. I changed combinations into combinations_with_replacement to make it work.

Comment: Nice! Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the set() method in order to prevent duplicates in what ever list you create.

this will do the job:

```
print(set(my_list))
```

Comment: Ah, that's true. But I want the order to be conserved. But I could use an ordered_set.